# Implementing skipWhile1 in attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

[Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) provides the function `takeWhile1` that consumes at least one character.

However, there is no analog for `skipWhile`. How can I implement this function `skipWhile1`?

*Note:* This question intentionally shows no research effort as it was answered Q&A-Style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible implementation:

```
import Control.Applicative

skipWhile1 p = skip p *> skipWhile p
```

This might actually be faster than @Uli's answer because `takeWhile` builds a result string, whereas `skipWhile` doesn't. Laziness might make them equivalent (ie. maybe `takeWhile` doesn't actually build the string if you don't use it); I can't test at the moment to verify this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Control.Monad.void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v%3avoid) together with `takeWhile1` to simply ignore the result:

```haskell
import Data.Attoparsec.Char8
import Control.Monad (void)

skipWhile1 :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser ()
skipWhile1 = void . takeWhile1
```