# Implementing takeTill1 in attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

[Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) provides the function `takeWhile1` that consumes at least one character.

However, there is no analog for `takeTill`. How can I implement this function `takeTill1`?

*Note:* This question intentionally shows no research effort as it was answered Q&A-Style.
While this question is similar to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22613161/2597135) the answer is not the same. I think the missing `takeTill1` is a potential hurdle for beginners and this question therefore deserves a separate answer.

Comment: To the downvoter: Please comment what you think is wrong with this question. Simply downvoting it, without explanation, will not make anything any better. I assume you're the person who serially downvotes my post. If you'd like something to be improved, I'd appreciate if you'd leave a comment instead of downvoting serially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to invert the predicate [`takeWhile1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.2.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v:takeWhile1) takes (see [this blogpost](http://techoverflow.net/blog/2014/01/03/haskell-invert-filter-predicate/) for a description on how to invert predicates if you are a beginner):

```haskell
takeTill1 :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser ByteString
takeTill1 p = takeWhile1 (not . p)
```

Also see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22613715/2597135) providing a fast implementation for `skipWhile1`.